# Infopath 2010 > is multiple selection list box allowed for Browser

Tags: sharepoint-2010, listbox, infopath2010

I may be missing something. I have a Multiple Selection List box in a Section. See attached pic. When I right click on the grpApplications and copy XPath it gives me /my:myFields/my:grpAccessOfficeEquipment/my:grpApplications when I right click for XPath on the fldApplicatins it gives me /my:myFields/my:grpAccessOfficeEquipment/my:grpApplications/my:fldApplications

In the code (code posted below) I am referencing the /my:myFields/my:grpAccessOfficeEquipment/my:grpApplications/my:fldApplications and I get no value. but I used /my:myFields/my:grpAccessOfficeEquipment/my:grpApplications I get a value for selected item in the listbox.

But I am still getting error NullReferenceException "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on string appName line. The AppID looks like this "\n\t\t\t262265264143\n\t\t" instead of whole number in debug. but when I click on the binocular is shows 262265264143 but with spaces/lines before and after this

```
XPathNavigator MainDS = MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator iterApp = MainDS.Select("/my:myFields/my:grpAccessOfficeEquipment/my:grpApplications", NamespaceManager);
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
while (iterApp.MoveNext())
{
    string AppID = iterApp.Current.Value;
    //int lookupID = Convert.ToInt16(value);
    XPathNavigator secAPPDS = DataSources["SupportEscalationList"].CreateNavigator();
    string appName = secAPPDS.SelectSingleNode("/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW[@ID = '" + AppID + "']/@ApplicationProcess", NamespaceManager).Value;
    sb.Append(appName);
    item["ApplicationProcess"] = sb.ToString(); // because applicationprocess column in target sp list is single text type column
}
```

Comment: ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/R7ZFs.png

Answer (score 0):

Says here multiple selection list boxes are supported in 2010 browser forms but not 2007 browsers forms. Hope that helps.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/infopath-2010-features-unavailable-in-web-browser-forms-HA101732796.aspx